# How to add DateTimePicker in ToolStrip?

Tags: c#, .net, datepicker, toolstrip

I want to add a datetimepicker to a ToolStrip control to show today's date, so is there any way to add the datetimepicker in ToolStrip?

**Example**:

[image]

Thank you.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

you can use this snippet :

```
var datePicker = new ToolStripControlHost(new DateTimePicker());
toolStrip1.Items.Add(datePicker);
```